# Change Community Wiki Answer

Tags: support, status-completed

I recently posted an [answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/114995?noredirect=1) for which i used Community Wiki option. Later I realized that SE is suggesting not to use the [Community wiki](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/04/22/putting-the-community-back-in-wiki/) thus I want to remove it with Moderator Assistance

Comment: I fixed it for you :)